# How to pass a serialized array to Symfony2 Command

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, serialization, command

I create a symfony2 command with one argument.
This argument is the result of serialize($array) function.

But, inside the command I'm not able to unserialize() the received argument, i always got an error:

```
Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 5 of 48 bytes in ...
```

This is a example of the array i want to send to the command:

```
$array = array('key1' => '$value1', 'key2' => '$value2')
```

When i serialize the array (serialize($array)) this is the result:

```
a:2:{s:4:"key1";s:7:"$value1";s:4:"key2";s:7:"$value2";}
```

I was thinking: maybe the problem is due to double quotes in the string (remember, is to send to a command as parameter), then, i apply the addslashes function:

```
addslashes(serialize($array))
```

This is the result:

```
a:2:{s:4:\"key1\";s:7:\"$value1\";s:4:\"key2\";s:7:\"$value2\";}
```

but im still receiving the same error when i try to unserialize the string inside the command execute() function.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED!!!
the problem is with the operative system command line and the double quotes.
There is a way to serialize the array and avoid double quotes as parameter in the command: encoding base64.

The solution is to encode the serialized array:

```
$serialized = serialize(array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2'));
//$serialized => a:2:{s:4:"key1";s:6:"value1";s:4:"key2";s:6:"value2";}

$base64 = base64_encode($serialize);
//$base64 => YToyOntzOjQ6ImtleTEiO3M6NjoidmFsdWUxIjtzOjQ6ImtleTIiO3M6NjoidmFsdWUyIjt9
```

As you can see there is no quotes in $base64(that's one of the goals of base64_encode() )
Then, you can easily decode the string with base64_decode

```
$serialized = base64_decode($base64);
//$serialized => a:2:{s:4:"key1";s:6:"value1";s:4:"key2";s:6:"value2";}

$array = unserialize($serialized);
//$array => array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2')
```

I hope this help somebody

Comment: Its not that practical, you need to encode separately, then paste it in your console. On my side (Windows with PHPStorm console) it works just with adding backslashes before doublequotes. `php bin/console my:myCommand {\"foo\":\"bar\"}`

Comment: @FabianPicone what happens if you have escaped double quotes in your code?

Comment: @vitoriodachef Good question, i tried it out, you have to escape the string escapes too `{\"foo\":\"b\\\"a\\\"r\"}`.